# Python Error : Cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python, collections, python-3.10

When I try to run my project I get this error. I've seen alot of people having this issue on here and I've tried their codes but It didn't work. I'm using Python 3.10.6. Where should I fix to solve it?

Error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Users/User/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

**init**.py

```
import _collections_abc
import sys as _sys

from itertools import chain as _chain
from itertools import repeat as _repeat
from itertools import starmap as _starmap
from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
from operator import eq as _eq
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
from _weakref import proxy as _proxy

try:
    from _collections import deque
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    _collections_abc.MutableSequence.register(deque)

try:
    from _collections import defaultdict
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: Did you mean [`typing.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Mapping)?

Comment: Which line produces that error? The code you have provided doesn't attempt that import, also, why are you using "private" modules for built-in libraries? Anyways, the error is telling you there is no such thing as `Mapping` in `collections` and so it can't import it, you should provide a [mre]

Comment: I don't know what's private modules are. I haven't touched anything in this file. It was like that when I opened the file __init__.py. What is private modules?

Answer (score -2):

Mapping class was introduced in Python 3.3

Try upgrading to a newer version of Python.

Comment: Their Python version seems to be 3.10.6